# How can I get the name of a form in my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I'm getting the ngModel name, but I also want to get the name of the form to which the element with the "validacion" directive belongs.

I strictly need to get the name of the form to which the HTML element belongs. I can have several forms so I need a dynamic solution. thank you very much

```
.directive('validacion', function ($timeout,$rootScope,validacionCampos,$compile) {

      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          require: 'ngModel',

          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  if (!ngModel){
                          console.log("no hay modal")
                  return;          
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside link function you can get form name like this way.

```
var formName = element.find("ng-form").attr("name");
```

Comment: thanks for anwer. I am putting this `console.log(element.find("form"))` and this is the result: https://i.imgur.com/9PKodTM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can get form name using `ng-form` in pure AngularJS way like below:

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="cityInput">
</ng-form>
```

In JavaScript you can print:

```
  console.log($scope.myForm);
```

Comment: I strictly need to get the name of the form to which the HTML element belongs. I can have several forms so I need a dynamic solution. thank you very much.

Comment: This solution is fulfilling the requirement of your question. You have not specify if there are multiple forms and how you want to access it. From next time make sure to provide more details.

Comment: "How can I get the name of a form in **my directive**?"